# Does declaring variables inside array methods affects performance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I was wondering if declaring variables inside an array method, like `reduce` would hurt performance.
Let's say I want to reduce an array of users to a `Map`:

```
const users = [
  {
    userName: "username1",
    age: 31,
    userLocation: "Ireland"
  },
  {
    userName: "username2",
    age: 45,
    userLocation: "Spain"
  },
  {
    name: "username3",
    age: 24,
    userLocation: "France"
  }
];
```

I'd like to create new objects and assign them as value to the map. Would declaring a variable like `val` to hold the new object, instead of passing it directly into the map's `set` method make the execution slower?

```
const userMap = users
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.age > 30) {
      const val = { name: curr.userName, location: curr.userLocation } 
      acc.set(curr.userName, val);
    }
    return acc
  }, new Map());
```

I've tried measuring execution time with `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`, but results were different each time.

Comment: As with almost all performance questions - not by any amount worth worrying about in 99% of cases. Write whatever's most readable, and come back to optimize only if it turns out to be a problem.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @VLAZ what an interesting read!

Comment: On the contrary, declaring it outside of the method would affect performance negatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends heavily on the JavaScript interpreter that will execute that code, but I feel confident in telling you that there would be no difference since that value is computed to be passed anyway and the JIT compiler is smart enough to see that that value is not being used by other parties bringing you back to the previous case. Having said that there are really a lot of optimizations that are done and although the logic of your code is preserved, the resulting bytecode is a long way off.